# Nextjs static export redirecting issue

Tags: javascript, .htaccess, redirect, next.js

I have an issue with redirecting in my Next.js app.

I did static export (`next build && next export`).

Host of the app is located in the subdirectory ([https://www.myhost.com/subdirectory/**[index.html](https://www.myhost.com/subdirectory/**%5Bindex.html) here]**) so I used `basePath: '/subdirectory'` in `next.config.js`.
Everything works just right on first sight.

Redirecting inside the app works just fine. But when user refresh the page on the other page then index - let's say the page is named **subpage** (https://www.myhost.com/subdirectory/subpage) the site doesn't redirect the user to subpage but rather goes to https://www.myhost.com/ (not even to the subdirectory in which the project is located).

I would very much appreciate someones help.

Here is `.htaccess` file.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
  RewriteRule . /index.html/ [L]

</IfModule>
```

If u need any other file, I can edit this post if u comment it.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming your `.htaccess` file is located at `/subdirectory/.htaccess`. These directives are written as if the app is in the document root, not the subdirectory.

> ```
> <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
>
>   RewriteEngine On
>   RewriteBase /
>   RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
>   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
>   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
>   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
>   RewriteRule . /index.html/ [L]
>
> </IfModule>
> ```

The last `RewriteRule` directive sends all requests to the document root. You need to:

1. Remove the slash prefix on the *substitution* string (`/index.html/`)
2. And remove the trailing slash. (Ordinarily this would result in a 404, unless path-info is enabled?)
3. Remove the `RewriteBase` directive altogether.
4. The `<IfModule>` wrapper is not required.

Taking the above points into consideration, try the following instead:

```
# /subdirectory/.htaccess

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule . index.html [L]
```

Comment: U are a life saver! Thanks! It works now :)  And yes, .htacces was a typo, I edited the question now :)