# Nextjs dynamic page doesn't appear when refreshing in the server (after build)

Tags: .htaccess, next.js, dynamic-pages

i have a problem in my nextjs application after build ,in the server , i have access to all pages but when i refresh a page with a dynamic path ( page article that is a folder contains a [id].js page , the id is the article title ) this error is shown on the navigator :

> #### Not Found
>
> The requested URL was not found on this server.
>
> Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu) Server at myDomain.com Port 80

My `.htaccess` file contains :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule (.*)$ $1.html
```

is there any problem in my htaccess file or i have to configure another file in my app code ?

Comment: Are you exporting your app as static HTML with `next export`?

Comment: Does this question help... [Nextjs static export redirecting issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69464328/nextjs-static-export-redirecting-issue)

Answer (score 0):

You have a single page app, you entry point is your root file.

You can fix this redirecting all routes to your root file.

https://www.sej-ko.dk/2017/03/29/routing-single-page-application-on-apache-with-htaccess/

Comment: i've followed exactly what is mentioned in this article , but when i navigate to all the pages (not only refreshing) , it returns to the home page ( my index.js file) !